# Can I transfer Windows commands to Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL)? If so, how?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have installed anaconda in Windows os, and I could use conda or jupyter commands in powershell.

Then I install Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL), but I can't find conda or other anaconda commands in my WSL Ubuntu shell.

Can I transfer these commands in Windows to WSL Ubuntu? If so, how?

Comment: You can run any Windows application from WSL as long as they are in the path, or you give the exact path to them

Comment: Learn from here https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop

Comment: the drives are mounted in `/mnt/` and you can access any files including executable files with the correct path

Comment: Comments before Jun. 11 2019 mainly talked about env para like PATH and interoperability, which I supposed, based on https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop.

Answer (score 0):

I've read docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop

It answers questions like how to run Windows .exe application in WSL.

For Anaconda commands (like anaconda, conda and jupyter), my tmp solution is to install Anaconda in WSL.